# Image-url helper with https in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How I can set the url with https instead http in image-url helper?

Now:

`<%= image_url('logo.png') %> -> http://`

I need this:

`<%= image_url('logo.png') %> -> https://`

Comment: Have you enable SSL on your rails application ?

Comment: No, but now works with https. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the file config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
 Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  url:                  ':s3_domain_url',
  path:                 ':class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename',
  storage:              :s3,
  s3_credentials:       Rails.configuration.aws,
  s3_permissions:       :public_read,
  hash_secret:          "",
  s3_protocol:          'https',
  default_url:          ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('profile-avatar.jpg')
)
```

Comment: This is for paperclip, but is usefull too. Thanks!